# Control and super keys randomly swapped on Kinesis Advantage

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

All of a sudden when I'm using my computer Ubuntu will start interpreting the super key as control and vice versa. It only happens to my external keyboard (Kinesis Advantage); the built-in laptop keyboard isn't affected. When it happens I have to reboot to get the keys back to normal.

`xev` output when the problem happens and I press Control on external keyboard:

```
KeyPress event, serial 39, synthetic NO, window 0x3600001,
    root 0xd4, subw 0x0, time 6496824, (10,1771), root:(1497,1773),
    state 0x0, keycode 134 (keysym 0xffec, Super_R), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

pressing Control on laptop keyboard:

```
KeyRelease event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x3600001,
    root 0xd4, subw 0x0, time 6599126, (7,2265), root:(1494,2267),
    state 0x4, keycode 105 (keysym 0xffe4, Control_R), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

I'm happy to provide any other debugging info that might help.

Comment: I'm running into the same thing with my Kinesis Advantage on 17.04.

Comment: I tried following the directions on the back of the keyboard and opened a text editor (vi), then, while holding the equals key down, I pressed:  p   This seems to have switched them back.

Comment: Ah. That works for me too. Not sure what the root cause is.

Comment: It's switching the 'modes' when you do that. Documented here: https://kinesis-ergo.com/support/advantage/